# extracting list items in r data frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a data frame with two columns: ID and product. The product contains a list of items like the ones below:

| ID | Product |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 'desk','chair','clock' |
| 2 | NA |
| 3 | 'pen' |

I want to extract every single product in a separate row with the corresponding ID, as below:

| ID | Product |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 'desk' |
| 1 | 'chair' |
| 1 | 'clock' |
| 3 | 'pen' |

It would be appreciated if you had any suggestions.

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput`?

Comment: @Quinten, I am new in R and don't have any idea about dput!
But I have edited the example table in the question to be identical to my real data.

Comment: Hi @Mohammad, no problem! Your question is clear. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) could help you a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `separate`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1,2,3),
  product=c('desk, chair, clock', NA, 'pen')
) 

df |> 
  separate_rows(product) |> 
  drop_na()
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>      id product
#>   <dbl> <chr>  
#> 1     1 desk   
#> 2     1 chair  
#> 3     1 clock  
#> 4     3 pen
```

Comment: Hi MarBlo. very close to what I want. just needs a sep option in the separate_rows().

Comment: @`Mohammad` that is not necessary here, as `tidyr`  recognizes the separator. If you feel better, you may add `sep=','`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `tidyr` lib `separate_rows`

```
library(tidyr)

df = df %>%
  separate_rows(Product, sep = ",")
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside the above answers, I tried this method and works fine as well.

```
result_df <-  unnest(df, Product)
```